# Half Life 1 bug? Menu only show some servers instead of all possibilites

Tags: half-life

after playing Half Life 1 online for a while and then restarting, this is what my menu looks like:

[image]

All the elements load an online server, instead of doing what they are supposed to (for example, Find Servers is supposed to open a window where you can choose servers).

Is this a bug? How to get it back to normal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like I fixed it.

The problem seems to have been the file `Half-Life\valve\resource\GameMenu.res` which got overwritten (probably a bug) in some way.

Reinstalling the default `GameMenu.res` fixed the problem.

Comment: Please use the checkmark located underneath the vote total on this answer to mark it as accepted. :) There's a 2 day grace period required before being able to do this for answering your own questions, but after that time has passed, you're able to mark it.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure how to get it back to normal, as an alternative, you can use the Steam Server Browser (If Steam is running, single-click its icon, then click Servers) to find games, just make sure you set the filter to Deathmatch Classic.

[image: Steam Server Browser should Deathmatch Classic games]

Comment: That is, assuming you're referring to Half-Life Deathmatch.

Comment: It's just the classic Half-Life 1, without Steam.

Comment: @meh: Then can I suggest updating HL1?  The newer versions of HL1 do use Steam.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your text in the gamemenu.res file with following text:

> "game menu"
>   {
>   "1"
>   {
>   "label" "#GameUI_GameMenu_ResumeGame"
>   "command" "ResumeGame"
>   "OnlyInGame" "1"
>   }
>   "2"
>   {
>   "label" "#GameUI_GameMenu_Disconnect"
>   "command" "Disconnect"
>   "OnlyInGame" "1"
>   "notsingle" "1"
>   }
>   "3"
>   {
>   "label" "#GameUI_GameMenu_PlayerList"
>   "command" "OpenPlayerListDialog"
>   "OnlyInGame" "1"
>   "notsingle" "1"
>   }
>   "4"
>   {
>   "label" ""
>   "command" ""
>   "OnlyInGame" "1"
>   }
>   "5"
>   {
>   "label" "#GameUI_GameMenu_NewGame"
>   "command" "OpenNewGameDialog"
>   "notmulti" "1"
>   }
>   "6"
>   {
>   "label" "#GameUI_GameMenu_LoadGame"
>   "command" "OpenLoadGameDialog"
>   "notmulti" "1"
>   }
>   "7"
>   {
>   "label" "#GameUI_GameMenu_SaveGame"
>   "command" "OpenSaveGameDialog"
>   "notmulti" "1"
>   "OnlyInGame" "1"
>   }
>   "8"
>   {
>   "label" ""
>   "command" ""
>   "notmulti" "1"
>   }
>   "9"
>   {
>   "label" "#GameUI_GameMenu_FindServers"
>   "command" "OpenServerBrowser"
>   "notsingle" "1"
>   }
>   "10"
>   {
>   "label" "#GameUI_GameMenu_CreateServer"
>   "command" "OpenCreateMultiplayerGameDialog"
>   "notsingle" "1"
>   }
>   //"11"
>   //{
>   //"name" "LoadDemo"
>   //"label" "#GameUI_GameMenu_PlayDemo"
>   //"command" "OpenLoadDemoDialog"
>   //}
>   "12"
>   {
>   "label" ""
>   "command" ""
>   "notsingle" "1"
>   }
>   "13"
>   {
>   "label" "#GameUI_GameMenu_ChangeGame"
>   "command" "OpenChangeGameDialog"
>   "notsteam" "1"
>   "notsingle" "1"
>   "notmulti" "1"
>   }
>   "14"
>   {
>   "label" "#GameUI_GameMenu_Options"
>   "command" "OpenOptionsDialog"
>   }
>   "15"
>   {
>   "label" "#GameUI_GameMenu_Quit"
>   "command" "Quit"
>   }
>   }